# Get parent and child records from different tables in MySql (one to many)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a parent table called orders and a child table of order_items. I need to fetch orders of a customer and corresponding order items for each orders. Below is the schema:

Orders:

```
Id   | Order_date | Order_value
-------------------------------
1234 | 2016-12-12 | 700.00
```

Order Items:

```
Id    | ProductId  | OrderId
----------------------------
8847  | shirt_blue | 1234
8848  | shirt_red  | 1234
```

I need an end result in JSON which looks like this:

```
{
   id: '1234',
   order_date: '2016-12-12',
   order_value: 700.00,
   Items: [
      {id: '8847', productid: 'shirt_blue' },
      {id: '8848', productid: 'shirt_red' }
  ]
}
```

What is the cleanest and fastest way to get these records from MySql ? I am using NodeJS/Node-MySql if it makes any difference.

Currently I am fetching order records first and looping over them in my app layer and fetching order item records and append them to each record. This is not very effective way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a shot to [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/), which is an ORM build for Node.js and supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite and MSSQL.
With use of Sequelize, you can create models that reflect database tables. First step is to instantiate the sequelize itself:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://user:pass@example.com:3306/dbname');
```

Then you are able to create models:

```
var Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
    order_date: Sequelize.DATE,
    order_value: Sequelize.STRING
});

Order.sync(); // this is run in order to reflect the changes in your database
```

You can also define relations between models (database tables) like that:

```
var OrderItem = sequelize.define('OrderItem', {
    // attributes etc...
});

OrderItem.belongsTo(Order); // this would add OrderId attribute to OrderItem, which is a Foreign Key to Order table
Order.hasMany(OrderItem); // Likewise
```

By creating the relations you are able to return `OrderItems` of specified `Order`:

```
Order.findById(1).then(function(order){
    order.getOrderItems().then(function(orderItems){
        // here you get all order items assigned to given order
    });
});
```

This is very comfortable solution in terms of creation of models (tables) and migrating them. You can also create your custom SQL statements and run them directly via the `sequelize` instance.
Check out documentation, it contains lots of examples and precisely describe most use cases.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of MySQL support JSON Object results.
This will let you return nested child arrays.

The benefit is you can write nested SQL queries (so SQL can optimize) instead of manually fetching all the child elements in Node.js.

[How do I generate nested json objects using mysql native json functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470949/how-do-i-generate-nested-json-objects-using-mysql-native-json-functions)