# MySQL query related entities from multiple child rows into json array

Tags: mysql, sql, json

This is my databasedesign with a many-to-many relation

```
table Tournament
TournamentId int
name varchar(45)

table User
UserId int
name varchar(45)

table Tournament_Users
Tournament_Id int
User_Id int
```

I am attempting to return all tournaments with a list of the tournament's users in a JSON format. I'm not sure if this is possible to do in the query or it's a javascript job? I tried to follow this [Returning child rows formatted as JSON in SQL Server queries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/10/09/returning-child-rows-formatted-as-json-in-sql-server-queries/) but I drowned in the example.

This is my current query

```
SELECT t.TournamentId, t.Name as tourName, u.UserId, u.Name as userName
FROM  Tournament_Users tu
LEFT JOIN  Tournaments t ON tu.Tournament_Id = t.TournamentId
LEFT JOIN  Users u ON u.UserId = tu.User_Id
```

[image: Query result]

So as a json result this looks like this:

[image: Json result 1]

Which seems pretty difficult for a client to work with. How can I convert it into a format like this?

[image: Json result 2]

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bc2ebf/3

Comment: To format the output of the FOR JSON clause automatically based on the structure of the SELECT statement, specify the AUTO option.

Comment: Provide table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table`) and example data for all table involved on sqlfiddle.com.. Then we can help you..

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post @RaymondNijland

Comment: Dear, you do not mention here the database name. i was effort for u on MSSQL but u remarks me bad.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but it says mysql in both the title and the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT('{"data": [', GROUP_CONCAT(`json`), ']}') `json`
FROM (
  SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'TournamentId', `t`.`TournamentId`,
      'tourName', `t`.`Name`,
      'users', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                 JSON_OBJECT(
                   'UserId', `u`.`UserId`,
                   'userName', `u`.`Name`
                 )
               )
    ) `json`
  FROM
    `Tournament_Users` `tu`
    LEFT JOIN
      `Tournaments` `t` ON `tu`.`Tournament_Id` = `t`.`TournamentId`
    LEFT JOIN
      `Users` `u` ON `u`.`UserId` = `tu`.`User_Id`
  GROUP BY `t`.`TournamentId`, `t`.`Name`
  ORDER BY `t`.`TournamentId`
) `der`;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9zaJF8Au9mvM4w5HhKHMzH/0).

Comment: thanks this works as intended. Keep in mind JSON_ARRAYAGG wasn't introduced until version 5.7.22

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql 8.0 then

```
SELECT json_object(
'TournamentId', t.TournamentId ,'tourName', t.Name ,'UserId' ,u.UserId, 'UserName' ,u.Name)
FROM  Tournament_Users tu
LEFT JOIN  Tournaments t ON tu.Tournament_Id = t.TournamentId
LEFT JOIN  Users u ON u.UserId = tu.User_Id
```

You can refer -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html

Comment: `JSON_OBJECT` isn't a MySQL 8.0 only function. `JSON_OBJECT` was already in MySQL in 5.7

Comment: This doesn't give me the format i desire as in the last image of my post instead it just gives me 4 rows in json format? Is there no way to squeeze it into 3 so I don't have duplicate rows for the same tournament? Thanks for your help

Comment: you have to use json_array with json_object.please check this-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470949/how-do-i-generate-nested-json-objects-using-mysql-native-json-functions