# Nested json object from mysql: error 'missing a closing quotation mark in string' even with static values

Tags: mysql, json

I'm attempting to generate a nested, hierarchical JSON from MySQL.

I keep getting the error message:

**Error Code: 3141. Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function cast_as_json: "Missing a closing quotation mark in string." at position 1026.**

I have attempted the following and always got the same error:

- enclosed the problematic column name in `...`
- enclosed the problematic column in JSON_QUOTE(...)
- replaced the problematic column by a static string which includes whitespace characters
- enclosed the problematic column in CAST( ... ) as JSON

The following tests made the problem disappear but they're obviously not an option:

- replaced the problematic column by a static string which DOES NOT include whitespace characters => problem does NOT occur
- replace the problematic column by a different column which does NOT contain whitespaces => problem does NOT occur

I've googled for hours and really don't know any further.

The question closely follows the pattern described in 
[How do I generate nested json objects using mysql native json functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470949/how-do-i-generate-nested-json-objects-using-mysql-native-json-functions/37474200)

Thanks for any ideas!

Cheers F

Comment: any luck? i'm facing similar issue.

Comment: did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Are you using GROUP_CONCAT? if so, there's a chance that it cuts your string out because it's too long resulting in invalid JSON string.

Try changing the [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) for ex 100000 characters length:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000;
```

I know it's a bit too late :)

Comment: Holly crap that worked for me!! Thanks a lot.