# How to combine and select JSON calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to combine 2 json and appear together? If I choose one that has childern (like click **MEN** button), then `childern` in **MEN** will appear. But if element don't have `childern`, then the click function is not active.

And if I click the **back** button, it will bring up the previous menu.

So, the first time, I want to bring up

- MEN
- WOMEN
- KIDS
- Customer Care
- Contact

And if I click the **"MEN"** button, will appear

- back
- accesoris
- cloting
- shoes

If I click the **"back"** button, it will return 1 step earlier. Not returning, like the first time.

You can see, This is my imagination to combine 2 json. I don't know how to combine 2 json. Maybe like this

```
$.each(first, second, function(i, value) {
```

```js
var first = [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "MEN",
        "children": [{
                "id": 10,
                "text": "back"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "text": "accesoris",
                "children": [{
                        "id": 110,
                        "text": "back"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 111,
                        "text": "hat",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 112,
                        "text": "belt",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "text": "cloting",
                "children": [{
                        "id": 120,
                        "text": "back"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 121,
                        "text": "blazer",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 122,
                        "text": "pants",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "text": "shoes",
                "children": [{
                        "id": 130,
                        "text": "back"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 131,
                        "text": "oxford",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 132,
                        "text": "chukka",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "WOMEN",
        "children": [{
                "id": 20,
                "text": "back"
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "text": "accesoris",
                "children": [{
                        "id": 210,
                        "text": "back"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 211,
                        "text": "ring",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 212,
                        "text": "glove",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "text": "cloting",
                "children": [{
                        "id": 220,
                        "text": "back"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 221,
                        "text": "tshirt",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 222,
                        "text": "dress",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "text": "shoes",
                "children": [{
                        "id": 230,
                        "text": "back"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 231,
                        "text": "sandals",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 232,
                        "text": "heels",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "KIDS"
    }
]
var second = [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Customer Care",
        "children": [{
                "id": 10,
                "text": "back"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "text": "Product Information"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "text": "Payment Information"
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "text": "Your Order"
            }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "Contact",
        "children": [{
                "id": 20,
                "text": "back"
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "text": "Careers"
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "text": "Affiliates"
            }]
    }
]

// Appears the first time
var text = [];
$.each(first, function(i, value) {
    text += '<a>' + value.text + '</a><br>';
    $('.result').html(text);
});

// Im not sure its correct, because im using first and second together
// var text = [];
// $.each(first, second, function(i, value) {
//     text[i] += '<a>' + value.text + '</a><br>';
//     $('.result').html(text[i]);
// });


// Function if a button is pressed
$(document).click('a', function(e) {
    if ($(this).text() == 'back') {
       // Go back one step, not back to the beginning
    } else {
        // function text() ---->  $('.result').html(text);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: your JSON first is not valid

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470949/how-do-i-generate-nested-json-objects-using-mysql-native-json-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so this a jQuery version

```js
var
  first = [
    { "id": 1,  "text": "MEN", "children": [
      { "id": 10, "text": "back" },
      { "id": 11, "text": "accesoris", "children": [
        { "id": 110, "text": "back" },
        { "id": 111, "text": "hat"  },
        { "id": 112, "text": "belt" }
      ]},
      { "id": 12, "text": "cloting", "children": [
        { "id": 120, "text": "back"   },
        { "id": 121, "text": "blazer" },
        { "id": 122, "text": "pants"  }
      ]},
      { "id": 13, "text": "shoes", "children": [
        { "id": 130, "text": "back"   },
        { "id": 131, "text": "oxford" },
        { "id": 132, "text": "chukka" }
      ]}
    ]},
    { "id": 2, "text": "WOMEN", "children": [
      { "id": 20, "text": "back" },
      { "id": 21, "text": "accesoris", "children": [
        { "id": 210, "text": "back"  },
        { "id": 211, "text": "ring"  },
        { "id": 212, "text": "glove" }
      ]},
      { "id": 22, "text": "cloting", "children": [
        { "id": 220, "text": "back"   },
        { "id": 221, "text": "tshirt" },
        { "id": 222, "text": "dress"  }
      ]},
      { "id": 23, "text": "shoes", "children": [
        { "id": 230, "text": "back"    },
        { "id": 231, "text": "sandals" },
        { "id": 232, "text": "heels"   }
      ]}
    ]},
    { "id": 3, "text": "KIDS" }
  ]
  ,
  second = [
    { "id": 1, "text": "Customer Care", "children": [
      { "id": 10, "text": "back" },
      { "id": 11, "text": "Product Information" },
      { "id": 12, "text": "Payment Information" },
      { "id": 13, "text": "Your Order" }
    ]},
    { "id": 2, "text": "Contact", "children": [
      { "id": 20, "text": "back"    },
      { "id": 21, "text": "Careers" },
      { "id": 22, "text": "Affiliates" }
    ]}
  ];
;

const
  fullList = first.concat(second) ,
  $myList  = $('#my-List') ;

var
  List_Level   = []       ,
  current_List = fullList ;

function ShowList_F()
{
  let xList = fullList;

  for (let x=0, xMax=List_Level.length; x<xMax; x++)
  {
    xList = xList[ List_Level[x] ].children;
  }

  $myList.empty()

  current_List = xList;

  for (let i=0, iMax=xList.length; i<iMax; i++)
  {
    let aClass = 'levelentry' + (xList[i].hasOwnProperty('children')?' PLUS':'');   // other possibility

    $myList.append( `<li class="root-level"><a class="${aClass}" data-ref="${i}">${xList[i].text}</a></li>`);
  }
}

ShowList_F(); // first attempt


$myList.on( "click", "a", function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let xItem = parseInt( $(this).data('ref') );

  if ($(this).text()==='back')                             // level Up
  {
    List_Level.pop()
    ShowList_F();
  }
  else if (current_List[xItem].hasOwnProperty('children')) // level Down (and same test)
  {
    List_Level.push(xItem);
    ShowList_F();
  }
})
```

```css
#my-List { cursor: pointer; list-style-type:none }
.PLUS::before { content: '- '}
.PLUS:hover::before { content: '+'}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="my-List"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi i have qustion last, pls answer.. What if it detects if you don't have childern? Or the last text. `<a class="levelentry PLUS" data-ref=1">MEN</a>` but if section "HAT" then class PLUS does not exist. `<a class="levelentry" data-ref=1">HAT</a>`... So PLUS only exists if have children.. Sorry keep you busy @MrJ

Comment: There are different ways to test if a key exists in a json element.
` var json_elm = {" keyA ": 1," keyB ": 2," keyC ": 3}; `
` if ('keyB' in json_elm) ... `
or 
` if (json_elm [` 'keyB']) ... `

the first is Boolean, the second returns the data value that should not be [null, 0, false] .. (any value> 0 == true)
I made your change request on the script in jQuery, with a 3rd possibility

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine two arrays together you can just use concat.

`var fullList = first.concat(second);`

Comment: Then, how do you select if clicked on children?

Answer (score 0):

so it's a complete solution, unfortunately I lost the habit of coding jQuery, so it's an ES6 solution (which I find really less complicated)

```js
var
  first = [
    { "id": 1,  "text": "MEN", "children": [
      { "id": 10, "text": "back" },
      { "id": 11, "text": "accesoris", "children": [
        { "id": 110, "text": "back" },
        { "id": 111, "text": "hat"  },
        { "id": 112, "text": "belt" }
      ]},
      { "id": 12, "text": "cloting", "children": [
        { "id": 120, "text": "back"   },
        { "id": 121, "text": "blazer" },
        { "id": 122, "text": "pants"  }
      ]},
      { "id": 13, "text": "shoes", "children": [
        { "id": 130, "text": "back"   },
        { "id": 131, "text": "oxford" },
        { "id": 132, "text": "chukka" }
      ]}
    ]},
    { "id": 2, "text": "WOMEN", "children": [
      { "id": 20, "text": "back" },
      { "id": 21, "text": "accesoris", "children": [
        { "id": 210, "text": "back"  },
        { "id": 211, "text": "ring"  },
        { "id": 212, "text": "glove" }
      ]},
      { "id": 22, "text": "cloting", "children": [
        { "id": 220, "text": "back"   },
        { "id": 221, "text": "tshirt" },
        { "id": 222, "text": "dress"  }
      ]},
      { "id": 23, "text": "shoes", "children": [
        { "id": 230, "text": "back"    },
        { "id": 231, "text": "sandals" },
        { "id": 232, "text": "heels"   }
      ]}
    ]},
    { "id": 3, "text": "KIDS" }
  ]
  ,
  second = [
    { "id": 1, "text": "Customer Care", "children": [
      { "id": 10, "text": "back" },
      { "id": 11, "text": "Product Information" },
      { "id": 12, "text": "Payment Information" },
      { "id": 13, "text": "Your Order" }
    ]},
    { "id": 2, "text": "Contact", "children": [
      { "id": 20, "text": "back"    },
      { "id": 21, "text": "Careers" },
      { "id": 22, "text": "Affiliates" }
    ]}
  ];
;

const
  fullList = first.concat(second)
  ,
  myList   = document.querySelector('#my-List')
  ,
  Messager = { 
    _zone : document.getElementById('MsgZone'),
    Text(msg) {
      this._zone.textContent = msg;
      setTimeout(that=>that._zone.textContent='', 900, this);
    }
  };

var
  List_Level   = [],
  current_List = fullList,
  LI_elm       = document.createElement('li');


function ShowList_F()
{
  let
    xList = fullList,
    showingTxt = '';

  List_Level.forEach( x=>{
    showingTxt += ` / ${xList[x].text}`
    xList=xList[x].children
  })

  while( myList.firstChild )
    { myList.removeChild( myList.firstChild ); }

  current_List = xList;

  xList.forEach((e,i)=>{
    let xLI = myList.appendChild(LI_elm.cloneNode(false));
    xLI.dataset.ref = i.toString();
    xLI.textContent = e.text;

    if (e.text==='back') { xLI.className='back' }
  })

  Messager.Text(showingTxt)
}


ShowList_F(); // first attempt


myList.onclick = function(e)
{
  if (!e.target.matches('li')) return;
  e.stopPropagation();

  let xItem = parseInt(e.target.dataset.ref);

  if (e.target.textContent==='back')
  {
    List_Level.pop()
    ShowList_F();
  }
  else if ( 'children' in current_List[ xItem ])
  {
    List_Level.push(xItem);
    ShowList_F();
  }
  else
  {
    Messager.Text('nothing to do with this click')
  }
}
```

```css
#my-List { cursor: pointer; list-style-type:square }
#MsgZone, .back { font-size: 0.8em; font-style: italic }
```

```html
<ul id="my-List"></ul>

<div id="MsgZone"></div>
```

Comment: And i dont understand ES6 :(

Comment: You should be doing it, jQuery has not changed since 2016. The W3C consortiom has gotten things right and ES6 has become bigger than jQuery.
ES6 is javascript, nothing else, besides jQuery too.
everything is in the standard doc:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript 
like this :
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: How to change this `let xLI = myList.appendChild(LI_elm.cloneNode(false));xLI.dataset.ref = i.toString();xLI.textContent = e.text;` Because, if your results will be like this `"<li data-ref="....">KIDS</li>"`. And I want to like this `<li class="root-level"><a class="levelentry">KIDS</a></li>`.. And why can't I change `document.querySelector('#my-List')` to `$('#my-List')`