# Returning array of json objects from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, aggregate-functions

I'm new to SQL so this may be a dumb question but I'm having trouble figuring out returning an array of JSON objects.

My code is

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
            'title', pc.title,
            'reviews', (SELECT CAST(CONCAT('[',
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    JSON_OBJECT(
                        'username',r.uname,
                        'review',r.review,
                        'date', r.date_added
                    )
                )
            , ']')
            AS JSON) FROM reviews r WHERE pc.pid=r.pid)
        ) AS JSON
        FROM product_comp AS pc;
```

When there are no reviews it properly returns an empty array and when there is one review it returns that review in an array. But if there are multiple reviews it returns an empty array. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate nested json objects using mysql native json functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470949/how-do-i-generate-nested-json-objects-using-mysql-native-json-functions)

Comment: Well @JoakimDanielson that would be the safe method using JSON_ARRAY function.. But  if you know how JSON structure works you can generate JSON with CONCAT and or GROUP_CONCAT functions also, it does not really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the error-prone work of formatting JSON using CONCAT, try using [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg).

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'title', pc.title,
  'reviews', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(
                 'username', r.uname,
                 'review', r.review,
                 'date', r.date_added
               )
             )
)
FROM product_comp AS pc
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews AS r ON pc.pid = r.pid
GROUP BY pc.pid
```

I have not tested this, but it should give you the right idea.