# JavaScript + MariaDB: SQL query to return array of json objects and remove `\` forward slash from response

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am applying a raw query into my sql (mariaDB) tables in javascript function.

::: Updated Question :::

Below is a javascript function to create a sql query in which i have also tried with the `JSON_ARRAY` and `JSON_OBJECT` methods as suggested in the answer.

```
public async getProducts() {
  try {
  let productTbl = '`products`';
  let prodImgTbl = '`product_images_ids`';
  let productImg = '`product_images`';

  let query = `SELECT 
  ${productTbl}.id AS productId,
  GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT(
    "imageId", ${prodImgTbl}.id, 
    "imageUrl", ${productImg}.thumbnail_image
  ))) imageData,

  FROM ${productTbl} 
  JOIN ${prodImgTbl} ON ${prodImgTbl}.product_id = ${productTbl}.id
  JOIN ${productImg} ON ${productImg}.id = ${prodImgTbl}.product_image_id
  GROUP BY ${productTbl}.id `

  let records = await pool.query(query);
  return records
  } catch (error) {
  throw error;
  }
}
```

Using this query i am getting the result in postman as below which is adding the `\` to the each key and value.

```
this.productList = [
  {
    "productId": 3,
    "imageData": "[{\"imageId\": 17, \"imageUrl\": \"/assets/images/321/1/1/1/image.jpg\"}],[{\"imageId\": 18, \"imageUrl\": \"/assets/images/322/image.jpg\"}]",
  }
]
```

As i tried to loop through the above collection and throws the error that: 
`TypeError: lists.imageData.map is not a function`

```
this.productList.map((lists) => {
  lists.imageData.map((data) => {
    data.imageId
  })
})
```

*So the result that i wanted to render is as below, so that i can loop through the records.*

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    productId: 3,
    imageData [
      {
        imageId: 18,
        imageUrl: /assets/images/321/image.jpg
      },
      {
        imageId: 17,
        imageUrl: /assets/images/322/image.jpg
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

SQL Query run in the adminer tool

```
SELECT 
`products`.id AS productId,
GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT(
  "imageId", `product_images_ids`.id, 
  "imageUrl", `product_images`.thumbnail_image
))) imageData
FROM `products`
JOIN `product_images_ids` ON `product_images_ids`.campaign_id = `products`.id
JOIN `product_images` ON `product_images`.id = `product_images_ids`.product_image_id
GROUP BY `products`.id
```

And here is a result [screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4891866/9441f4e6fb74af355ceb6041d8f9027a) that i am getting in adminer.

I have checked with the [json_arrayagg](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_arrayagg/) and also [json_objectagg](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_objectagg/) but can not able to create an array of json objects.

P.S: MySQL version: 5.5.5-10.3.22-MariaDB

Comment: you can build a json in mysql or you do it in javascript,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `CONCAT`inside `GROUP_CONCAT` and create `JSON` object here

I am not sure if npm `mariadb` module will figure out the structure

```js
let query = `SELECT 
  ${productTbl}.id AS productId,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('{imageId:"'${prodImgTbl}'", imageUrl:"'${productImg}.thumbnail_image'"}')) imageData
  FROM ${productTbl} 

  JOIN ${prodImgTbl} ON ${prodImgTbl}.product_id = ${productTbl}.id
  JOIN ${productImg} ON ${productImg}.id = ${prodImgTbl}.product_image_id
  GROUP BY ${productTbl}.id`
```

If that doesn't work try cast it to JSON type ( the whole GROUP_CONCAT or every expression inside it)

```js
CAST(
  CONCAT(
    '[', GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT('{"imageId": "'${prodImgTbl}'", 
        "imageUrl": "'${productImg}.thumbnail_image'"}')),']') 
  AS JSON) imageData
```

If you are using the latest mariadb version there is [JSON_OBJECT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_object/)

```js
GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT("imageId", ${prodImgTbl}, "imageUrl", ${productImg}.thumbnail_image)) imageData
```

---Edit

You could call `JSON.parse` on each `imageData`

```js
this.productList = map(pr => ({...pr, imageData: JSON.parse(pr.imageData)}))
```

[Apparently there was similar question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470949/how-do-i-generate-nested-json-objects-using-mysql-native-json-functions/37474200#37474200) and here they suggest creating the whole JSON in query.

```js
`SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'productId',
  ${productTbl}.id,
  'imageData',
  CAST(
    CONCAT(
      '[', GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT('{"imageId": "'${prodImgTbl}'", 
          "imageUrl": "'${productImg}.thumbnail_image'"}')),']') 
  AS JSON)
  )
  FROM ${productTbl} 

  JOIN ${prodImgTbl} ON ${prodImgTbl}.product_id = ${productTbl}.id
  JOIN ${productImg} ON ${productImg}.id = ${prodImgTbl}.product_image_id
  GROUP BY ${productTbl}.id`
```

Unfortunately you'd still have to call `JSON.parse`

```js
let records = JSON.parse(await pool.query(query));
```

[There is also JSON_OBJECTAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

```js
let query = `SELECT 
  ${productTbl}.id AS productId,
  JSON_OBJECTAGG(${prodImgTbl}, ${productImg}.thumbnail_image) imageData
  FROM ${productTbl} 

  JOIN ${prodImgTbl} ON ${prodImgTbl}.product_id = ${productTbl}.id
  JOIN ${productImg} ON ${productImg}.id = ${prodImgTbl}.product_image_id
  GROUP BY ${productTbl}.id`
```

But I think you'd still have to do some concatenation to make above as an array and call `JSON.parse` one way or another.

Comment: Hello sir, I am getting the result using your suggested answer but it is not a perfect json objects. Please review my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I guess in the future queries it will become more difficult to manage by this way, and i found one good package of npm [ https://sequelize.org/master/ ]